# Create JS Date on Java

Tags: javascript, java

So I got a parser service on Java consumed by a JS application. This JS application requires a js Date. Is it possible for my Java service to parse a Date to a JS readable Date? how?

Easy way is to just send an ISOstring or send it in ms and then parse the  values into dates in the JS application, but that more or less ruins the idea.

Comment: Why does sending a timestamp "ruin the idea"? What idea?

Comment: Thought about using libraries like https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time?

Comment: @Pointy the idea was to parse everything as the app in js needed it, so if I still have to parse something there... see what I mean? I need the timestamp as a Date object for js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be talking about [serialization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Serialization), a millisecond moment in UTC can be represented as either a java object or a javascript object.

You should be able to send time in milliseconds between java and javascript, and build the object accordingly.

Also, using ISO date format is also valid and in a lot of cases, encouraged.

I think you might be confusing parsing with serialisation.

When you parse something, for example you want a parser that will convert `string` to `integer` you will use the data on the string to find (parse) to an integer.

When you serialise you transform the current state of an object into its `serialised` representation, that can be read by a different language or program and be `deserialised` back to something that represents its previous state.

In contrast with a parsed integer that is no longer a string.

Comment: Going into more depth, the point for the Java server parser is so that the data can be directly used in the Dygraph graph library which requires arrays, in the array it specifies and requires a Date object.

Although it is possible to get a string in ISO format or the value in ms, this would imply that in the JS app I'd need to parse these date values with new Date(), and would prefer if all of this could be solved on the Java server

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want a Java Date() object to become a Javascript Date() object. This can't be done directly.

That's why is OK to "parse" this new value as ms or iso string, because you are not parsing, but rather serialising and deserialising.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was aiming for. so there's no way to accomplish what I want then?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, no, you can't. But you can abstract that responsibility to a library or framework that will do it without you writing the code. But that's a different concept.

I don't think there is a way, but i leave with a different question that i think you need to investigate too. What's the difference between Parsing and Serialisation?

Comment: Check my last edit, i added my understanding of parsing vs serialisation.

Comment: Thanks Luis, I definitely didn't get what I was looking for, but I now understand what you mean and will research a bit more by myself, thanks for your answer and time